# Magento 2 : Where Does Sample-Data Contain CSS Modifications

Tags: magento2, css, sample-data, home-page

On Magento 2, There are tiles and stuff on homepage in luma theme with sample data, and they seem to have css classes. Where are these classes? are they from sampledata?

Thanks alot.

Comment: These links should be helpful to you. 
- [link]http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html
- [link]http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

The demo styling is pulled in from `/pub/media/styles.css`, I don't have the sample data available but I presume there will be some layout XML within the sample module which adds that css file.

**Edit**

It looks like the CSS file might be added via PHP:

https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=styles.css

Comment: just for the record, since I am digging into this, the style.css luma bits are in the CmsSampleData